# Inner join query with multiple cases

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm trying to add a new case in a join query, but it's not affecting the results.

I have a table with user posts, the query checks for who is friend of the user (by user_id) then checks if the post has been flagged 5 or more times. 'Till here is working fine. I want it to check now if the post is public. So  in this case it should ignore the friendship case.

The working Query before new case added:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_posts
        FROM mutamba_posts 
        INNER JOIN 
        (
           SELECT aluno_id 
           FROM mutamba_amigos
           WHERE mutamba_amigos.amizade_id IN 
           (
              SELECT amizade_id FROM mutamba_amigos WHERE aluno_id = '{$myid}'
           )
           GROUP BY aluno_id
        ) mutamba_amigos ON mutamba_amigos.aluno_id  = mutamba_posts.aluno_id  
        WHERE mutamba_posts.post_flags < 5
        ORDER BY mutamba_posts.post_date DESC";
```

After added the new case check (doesn't do anything):

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM mutamba_posts 
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT aluno_id 
   FROM mutamba_amigos
   WHERE mutamba_amigos.amizade_id IN 
   (
      SELECT amizade_id FROM mutamba_amigos WHERE aluno_id = '{$myid}'
   )
   GROUP BY aluno_id
) mutamba_amigos ON mutamba_amigos.aluno_id  = mutamba_posts.aluno_id  
WHERE mutamba_posts.post_flags < 5
  OR (mutamba_posts.post_visibility = 'show_all' AND mutamba_posts.post_flags < 5)
ORDER BY mutamba_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}";
```

Will appreciate any help.

Edit 2: I'm sorry for taking too long to come back, I was away.

here are my tables and some sample data.

Posts TBl:

```
post_id| aluno_id | post_text | post_flags | post_visibility |post_date

--69---|-----9----|Hello world|------0-----|------show_all-- |2015-01-19     
--70---|-----2----|Hi friends |------0-----|------friends----|2015-01-19 
--71---|-----1----|somedays.. |------2-----|------friends----|2015-01-19
```

Friendship TBl:

```
id | aluno_id | amizade_id | bloqueado | date
24 |----2-----|-----33-----|-----0-----|2015-01-02 
25 |----1-----|-----34-----|-----0-----|2015-01-02 
26 |----1-----|-----35-----|-----0-----|2015-01-02
27 |----2-----|-----35-----|-----0-----|2015-01-02 
28 |----9-----|-----36-----|-----0-----|2015-01-02
```

The expected output, the student 1 and 2 (aluno_id 1 and aluno_id 2) will be able to see their own posts because they are friends and the post from student 9 aluno_id 9 because it's set to `show_all`. However student 9 `aluno_id 9` will only be able to see his own post nothing more because he has no friends.

Comment: `WHERE x OR (y AND x)` is the same as `WHERE x`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem in your query is you are checking both `mutamba_posts.post_visibility = 'show_all' and mutamba_posts.post_flags < 5`.

To eliminate `mutamba_posts.post_flags < 5` when visiblility is `public` you cannot use `and` operator between them instead use `OR` operator.  Try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mutamba_posts 
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT aluno_id 
   FROM mutamba_amigos
   WHERE mutamba_amigos.amizade_id IN 
   (
      SELECT amizade_id FROM mutamba_amigos WHERE aluno_id = '{$myid}'
   )
   GROUP BY aluno_id
) mutamba_amigos ON mutamba_amigos.aluno_id  = mutamba_posts.aluno_id  
WHERE mutamba_posts.post_flags < 5
  OR mutamba_posts.post_visibility = 'show_all'
ORDER BY mutamba_posts.post_date DESC
```

**Update :**

```
SELECT mutamba_posts.* 
FROM mutamba_posts 
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT aluno_id 
   FROM mutamba_amigos
   WHERE mutamba_amigos.amizade_id IN 
   (
      SELECT amizade_id FROM mutamba_amigos WHERE aluno_id = '{$myid}'
   )
   GROUP BY aluno_id
) mutamba_amigos ON mutamba_amigos.aluno_id  = mutamba_posts.aluno_id  
WHERE mutamba_posts.post_flags < 5
  OR mutamba_posts.post_visibility <> 'show_all'
Union all
SELECT * 
FROM mutamba_posts 
WHERE mutamba_posts.post_visibility = 'show_all'
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

Comment: Why do you need `AND 1=1`?

Comment: @Barmar - Yes it is not needed. slightly confused sorry but it won't make any difference

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, It's not working, It's not having any effect. I dont know if you understand me, what I want it to do is to ignore the join if  `post_visibility = 'show_all' ` .

Comment: @NoDisplayName still the same,  the only thing  is that i have a previous query exaclty the same but it gets the count ` SELECT COUNT(*)`  is throwing an error now  => "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns". But as for the posts, they remain only visible to friends as if it's ignoring the `post_visibility' check.

Comment: @sunrisepoet - can you add sample data and expected output

Comment: @NoDisplayName, I just updated the question, sorry for the delay, as I was away.

Comment: @sunrisepoet - Looks like you tried to edit my answer and post the sample data and expected output. Edit got rejected. You should add the sample data and expected output in the question.